# How to solve : "the element div cannot be nested within the element 'updatepanel' "

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webforms

I want to use update panel and div inside update panel but i got error:
 the element div cannot be nested within the element 'updatepanel'. 
This is my code :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

    <div style="overflow:scroll">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewHome" runat="server" Width="100%"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewHome_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="30" ShowFooter="True">

               <Columns>

                   <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Options</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div style="width:100%"> <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1"  NavigateUrl='<%#"/RPT/WebForm1.aspx?order_id=" +Eval("Request number")+"&DEPT ID=" +Eval("DEPT ID")+"&Test Id=" +Eval("Test Id")+"&Culture=" +Eval("Culture")%>' runat="server">Print Result</asp:HyperLink></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Patient MRN#</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <div style="width:100%">  <asp:Label ID="lblpatient" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Patient No") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Patient Name</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <div style="width:100%"> <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Patient Name") %>'></asp:Label></div> 
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Order Number</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <div style="width:100%"> <asp:Label ID="lblorder" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Request number") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


            </Columns>


        </asp:GridView>
        </div>

        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

How to solve this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An updatepanel can contain a ContentTemplate , so add ContentTemplate like this :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <div style="overflow:scroll">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewHome" runat="server" Width="100%"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewHome_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="30" ShowFooter="True">

               <Columns>

                   <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Options</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div style="width:100%"> <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1"  NavigateUrl='<%#"/RPT/WebForm1.aspx?order_id=" +Eval("Request number")+"&DEPT ID=" +Eval("DEPT ID")+"&Test Id=" +Eval("Test Id")+"&Culture=" +Eval("Culture")%>' runat="server">Print Result</asp:HyperLink></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Patient MRN#</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <div style="width:100%">  <asp:Label ID="lblpatient" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Patient No") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Patient Name</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <div style="width:100%"> <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Patient Name") %>'></asp:Label></div> 
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Order Number</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <div style="width:100%"> <asp:Label ID="lblorder" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Request number") %>'></asp:Label></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


            </Columns>


        </asp:GridView>
        </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert the div inside the ContentTemplate tag, like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="overflow:scroll">
            //stuff

        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add `<ContentTemplate>` section inside `<asp:UpdatePanel>` to hold the div element, because an `UpdatePanel` can only have `ContentTemplate` section:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="overflow:scroll">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewHome" runat="server" Width="100%"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewHome_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="30" ShowFooter="True">
            <%-- gridview contents --%>
        </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Reference:

[validation (xhtml5): the element 'div' cannot be nested within the element 'updatepanel'](https://forums.asp.net/t/1923001.aspx?validation%20xhtml5%20the%20element%20div%20cannot%20be%20nested%20within%20the%20element%20updatepanel%20)